# Unable to compare two values within the 2D array

Tags: java

I am working on a problem in which I have to compare two values within the 2D array but I am unable to get the output. Kindly help me to come out of this problem. Here's a glimpse of my code:

```
int arr[][]=new int[N][N];
for(j=0;j<arr.length;j++)
{
    for(k=0;k<arr[j].length;k++)
    {
        if(arr[j][k]==arr[j][k+1])
            c++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Come out of what problem? Do you get an error/exception or not the expected result? Please update and clarify your question.

Comment: In your code you're definitely getting `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` in line `arr[j][k]==arr[j][k+1]` because k+1 gets outside array bounds.  Does this resolve your problem?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you will get an ArrayOutOfBoundsException due to the comparison `if(arr[j][k]==arr[j][k+1])`. This happens when you reach the last element of the array since when k is strictly less than `arr[j].length`, then k+1 element doesn't exist.

Maybe you want to change the condition to `k<arr[j].length-1`. But I am not sure what you actually what to achieve with the code.